# php : Alternate way to upload photo to facebook wall

Tags: php, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

I use below code to post a photo on wall usually

```
$attachments = array( 
            'message' => $mess,
             'access_token' => $access_token
          );
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachments['image'] ='@'.realpath($filename);
$photoz = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachments);
```

I use Google app engine, so above wont work, so i followed below method

```
  $filename ="prof.jpg";
  $im ='@'.realpath($filename);
   $post = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$aid."/photos?access_token=".$access_token."&message=hellohi&source=".$im."&method=POST";
 $upload = fetch_url($post);
    echo $upload;
```

But when i get the error #324) **Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":32**

Can i know what is the reason?and where am i wrong?

p.s - $im returns @/base/data/home/apps/s~myphotoapp/1.362007154292719350/prof.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i get the error #324) **Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":32**
>
> Can i know what is the reason?

Simple: You did not *actually* upload a file as an HTTP upload.

The data has to be encoded in a format known as `multipart/form-data` – whereas you are just putting the parameters into an URL, which is something different.

So either you go and do some research, how to send data as `multipart/form-data` within the scope of techniques Google App Engine offers you;

or … if your images publicly are accessible via HTTP, you can also switch the `source` parameter for a parameter called `url`, in which you give the HTTP URL under which the image is retrievable.